# Converting a complex timestamp to normal time in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5, angular8

I have a time stamp like

> 2021-03-12T14:55:35.454Z

I want to convert that into normal time like this (below) in the ts file

> 2:55pm

I am working in angular. Please help if you guys know. I have tried searching other stackoverflow questions but I couldn't find the exact solution

Please help if you guys know

Comment: have you looked into the [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library?

Comment: Moment is now deprecated in favor of [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)

Comment: Could you please post your code? What you have tried so far? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, Angular's built-in DatePipe.

if you want to use it in html

```
{{ yourDate| date: 'shortTime'}}
```

or in component file:

```
const myDate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(rawDate,'shortTime' );
```

rawDate is your complex timestamp.

to know more about formats available , head on to https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

Moment js is a good option for timezone. You can use datepipe in angular Which is correctly mentioned by prashant vats.

if you want to just convert iso to am/pm format you can use below method as well.

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  convertedtime = null;
  public convertTime(date: string): string {
    if( !date ) {
      return null;
    }
    const dateTimeArr = date.split("T");
    const timeArr = dateTimeArr[1].split(":");
    const hour = +timeArr[0] > 12 ? +timeArr[0] % 12 : (timeArr[0] === "00") ? 12 : timeArr[0];
    const min = timeArr[1];
    const ampm = +timeArr[0] > 12 ? "pm": "am";
    return `${hour}:${min}${ampm}`;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.convertedtime = this.convertTime("2021-03-12T14:55:35.454Z");
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y6aic1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts